# Adding new branches in Android studio

Tags: android, git

I am trying to add a new branch for my project in Android Studio. So I choose

**app->git->repository->branches**

However, git doesn't let me to create a new one.

[image: android]

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: How thought? I used this git branch 1.01_intro and got back fatal:Not a valid object name: 'master'

Comment: @Theo The comment by Ravi appears to have uncovered the root cause of the problem: Your Git setup is corrupt, hence Android Studio is politely refusing to do anything for you.  What happens from the console when you type `git status` ?

Comment: it shows: Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
...Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

Comment: You have unstashed changes.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: @MuratK. Good point, but I don't know if it's possible to branch in Git from a bare repo.  Do you know if this be possible?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I never encountered such a case so I'm afraid I have no idea. Maybe OP will try it out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments above, it appears you are working in a fresh Git repo which does not yet even have an initial commit.  The default branch in Git is `master` (the equivalent of "trunk" in SVN), but it seems that this branch isn't yet available for branching.  You should commit whatever work you have done so far first via:

```
git add <file>
```

for each file you want to include, followed by

```
git commit -m 'My first commit'
```

At this point, you should be able to create branches from your `master` branch.  To verify this, first try doing

```
git branch 1.01_intro
```

from the bash command line.  If that works, then try doing the same from within Android Studio.

Comment: Can I somehow restart git,because I think I messed things app.lol.

Comment: The answer with the bash console is always favorable, because to achieve the initial commit with the AS git-UI is really not easy to accomplish.

Comment: When you say "messed things up" what actually happened?

Comment: @Theo Create a new project and use `git init` inside the folder. From there you can do the `git add .` and so on. After that AS should recognize the git project.

Comment: @Murat. I will try your solution,but man it is annoying to create my android from the start.

Comment: @Theo I find these config problems to be the most annoying and time consuming hurdles to software.  Once your environment is setup, the actual coding usually isn't so bad, thanks to resources like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new branch you are not allowed to have any unstaged changes in your current branch which is in this case your master branch. To fix this you can either add/commit the changes and then branch it

To add/commit you can use the AS UI Interface with `Git -> Add` and `Git -> Repository -> Push...`. And then create a new branch

or stash it from the beginning.

To stash the changes go to `Git -> Repository -> Stash Changes...` and then you can create a new branch and apply the stash with `UnStash Changes...`